# Control/space characters not allowed using MD5 in Django cache backend

Tags: python, django, memcached, hash-function

I am using caching for my site using using. This is giving the following error:

```
"Control/space characters not allowed (key="\xebw\x1b}\xae\xa3\xb8\x18\xc4\xb5\xce\x0c%\x13'\xed")".
```

The code which I am using is as follows:

```
def hash_key(key, key_prefix, version):
    new_key = '%s :%s :%s' % (key_prefix, version, key)
    if len(new_key) > 250:
        m = hashlib.md5()
        m.update(new_key)
        new_key = m.digest()

    return new_key
CACHES = {
    'default': {
       'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
       'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1.11211',
       'KEY_FUNCTION': hash_key,
    }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), if you haven't yet, for more on asking questions in a way that will attract quality answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `m.hexdigest()` instead of `m.digest()`.  The data in the error message is 16 bytes, the length of the binary hash data.  It appears you want the 32-character ASCII representation, which is what `hexdigest` provides.

[Docs, for Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest)

Comment: @Iti You're welcome! The way folks here expect you to convey that is to click the checkmark next to the answer that most effectively answered your question, and to click the up arrow next to any answer that was helpful. Doing so will give others an incentive to answer your questions in the future. Plus, you get reputation points when you accept an answer (the checkmark), as does the answerer.

Comment: I have done that . Since I don't have 15 reputations it will not count in public.

Comment: @Iti I had forgotten :) .  I believe you can accept, even if you can't yet upvote - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers .  Thank you for being aware!  Not every new user is.